# Exchanging Li-ion batteries: what to take into account?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am looking forward to exchange a swollen Chinese Li-ion battery with a 'normal' one.
The device had this one:
https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32908652788.html

and I am considering to exchange it with this one:

https://api-lemona.lt/TI/En/Pdf/accu-18650_spcb.pdf

The voltage is the same, charging voltage as well. Is there anything else, one should pay attention to by using a different model of a battery? Charging happens through the device it self, so let's say that the charging conditions will remain the same and I have no influence on this.

In case it is not ethical or whatever to discuss the particular products, let's answer the question neutral:
What are the main specifications to take into account when exchanging batteries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main things of concern are, at least for lithium-ion single-cell batteries:

- Ensure the new battery has the same number of cells as the old one--*do not* replace a single-cell battery with a 2-cell battery or vice versa
- Ensure the new battery is the same chemistry as the old one (don't replace a LiFePO₄ with a standard lithium cell, for instance)
- Ensure the new battery has the same or higher charge and discharge current ratings (that's *current* rating, not C number; you'll have to convert if they have different capacities)

  - Note that what really matters here is what current the battery actually is charged and discharged at, so if you can identify that, *that* is your real limit, not necessarily the old battery's ratings. It's unlikely the battery is being used right at its limit (and the new one really shouldn't be either!).

These are the only real safety concerns, but you probably also want to ensure the capacity of the new battery is about the same or larger. Otherwise you might find you have nowhere near the battery life you used to!

Comment: Thank you! Could you comment on first and second points. Why is it bad/unsafe to have a different amount of cells in new battery? (in case it has some integrated protection mechanism?) and what is the problem by using another battery with different chemistry?

Comment: @Vytautas Having multiple cells requires special charging circuitry to ensure they remain balanced; if they get unbalanced it can result in one of the cells being destroyed by overcharging before the others are fully charged. Keeping the same chemistry is because of slight differences in how you have to charge batteries of different chemistries; LiFePO₄ has a slightly higher end voltage, for instance, so putting a regular LiPo in a device with a LiFePO₄ charger will overcharge it, damaging the cell and potentially causing a fire.

Comment: Ok, so vice versa isn't so bad, just LiPo instead of LiFePO. Thank you. But shouldn't it be solved by the protection circuitry (if you check the pdf link?)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing is to make sure the charge and discharge rates aren't exceeded. Per the datasheet these are 2.5A for the 18650 and not specified for the 454261 (your first link).